# IIS7 rewrite rule is not working

Tags: iis-7

I'm attempting to do a rewrite rule for a non-aspx site. It's just html files.

Here is what I have in the web.config at the moment. I have tried various rules and both integrated and classic pipeline mode yet nothing works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="eyeswidewhat.net" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.eyeswidewhat.net/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  This will redirect non-www to www.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="RedirectToWWW" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^eyeswidewhat\.net$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.eyeswidewhat.net/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```